# Ebean is not cascading persistence with Play-2.5(OneToMany)

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

Here are my models.

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends Model {
  String username;
  @Id
  String id;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Tag:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag extends Model {

  @Constraints.Required
  public String tag;
}
```

Persistence code(Removed unnecessary code):

```
User user = new User();
user.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
user.username = username; // String
user.tags = tags; // list of tags;
Ebean.save(user);
```

I am calling **Ebean.save(user)** after adding tags to user object.
Tags added on user are not persisted to database. I am also not seeing any exception, other fields of user get persisted but not tags. 
Am I missing something?

Note: I am using postgres.

Comment: can you post the snip of code where you are persisting the information ?

Comment: Could you also add [configuration to log sql](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase#How-to-configure-SQL-log-statement) and post what is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @marcospereira. 
I was missing id field in Tag model. After enabling debugging and sql logging I noticed warning in logs. 
The correct way to create Tag class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public String id;
  public String tag;
}
```

but It is weird why Ebean is doing that.

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: Ebean allows entities to not have an @Id property ... With these entities being useful for reporting purposes.

Comment: Note for best cross DB support it is recommended not to specify a ID generation strategy and instead let Ebean choose an appropriate strategy based on the DB platform.